# How to get helper to wait on DOM element to be created? [meteor]

Tags: jquery, dom, meteor, twitter, meteor-blaze

I am trying to render embedded tweets in my application.  I have a mongo collection of tweet Ids (tweetId).  I am using the (document) _id as the id in the div so that Twitter can target a specific element for the tweet.

template:

```
{{#each mongoCollectionOfTweetIds}}
  <div id={{_id}}> 
     {{embeddedTweet}} 
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

In the "embeddedTweet" helper I run:

```
targetElement = document.getElementById("#{this._id}")
twttr.widgets.createTweet("#{this.tweetId}", targetElement)
```

I know this._id is accurate via console.log testing.  I have also verified that looking for the dom element above ends up undefined.

So, it seems the data context is there via meteor, but I am calling twttr too fast (ie. before the dom element exists from getelementbyid)?

The challenge is that twttr requires a unique dom ID for each call.

Hoping there is a better pattern here.

Answer (score 0):

you have to wait until the template's been rendered before you can go after the DOM elements.

```
Template.Foo.onRendered(function() {
});
```

in there, you can run your queries to find your DOM children and call to the twitter API.

helpers can run multiple times while data is being updated and the template is rendering, so anything done in helpers should be idempotent. and ideally not hit an API.

Comment: I added a console.log to the onRendered and onCreated to test, but it seems they only run once.  I expected them to run for every item in the collection via {{#each}}, but it seems the dom is updated, but the template not re-rendered.  As a 2nd attempt, I moved the twttr call to a method on the server, but it seems the client is the only one that understands that library since I load it via a script in <head>

Comment: by default, the onRendered() will run just the one time. if all the DOM elements are not there when it does run, you can get it to run again by putting something reactive inside an autorun(), like Template.currentData() or a find() (i.e. whatever the source of your tweet data is).